# How to map a hibernate entity to another with constants

Tags: java, hibernate

I learning Hibernate, using a legacy database. There are two entities, one that in theory is contained in the other. In the database however only the contained element knows that it is being held by this container rather than another container, based on a containertype constant.

The classes are something like:

```
class Contained{
  private Long containerType;
  private Long containerId;

  ...

  @Column(name="containerType")
  public Long getContainerType(){
    return containerType;
  }
  @Column(name="containerId")
  public Long getContainerId(){
    return containerId;
  }
}

class Container1{
  private Long id;
  ...
  private Contained contained;

  public Contained getContained(){
    return contained;
  }
}
```

Is there a way in hibernate to map the contained entity within the container? Where the container type is a constant in the Contained entity.

Answer (score 1):

Why isn't the Contained an [@Embeddable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html)?

Comment: I didnt use @Embeddable because I thought that it was only used when the contained is always inside of the container, and it is possible for the contained to be moved to another container

Answer (score 0):

are you maybe looking for enum mappings, like so:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private CONTAINER_TYPE container_type;
```

with CONTAINER_TYPE being an enum ?